# $.fn.dataTable.render.moment is not a function with npm

Tags: javascript, npm, datatable, datatables

I got a basic issue in my application that i can't solve : i would like to format date in my datatable using moment like i have done in this script :

```js
$().ready(function() {
    const FROM_PATTERN = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS';
    const TO_PATTERN   = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm';

    // liste des documents - INDEX 
    var listDocuments = $("#list-documents").DataTable({
        processing:true,
        serverSide:true,
        scrollY:620,
        autoWidth:true,
        pageLength:25,
        responsive:true,
        scroller: {
            loadingIndicator:true 
        },
        ajax: {
            url: $("#list-documents").attr('data-json')
        },
        columns: [
            {data:'nom',name:'nom'},
            {data:'uri',name:'uri',
            "fnCreatedCell": function(nTd,sData,oData,iRow,iCol) {
                $(nTd).html("<a href='" + oData.uri + "'>"+ oData.uri +"</a>")
            }
        },
            {data:'updated_at',name:'updated_at',
            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment(FROM_PATTERN,TO_PATTERN),
        },
            {data:'action',name:'action',orderable:false,searchable:false},
        ]
    })
    .on('draw',function() {
        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip()
    })
})
```

The problem i had is that i got this error `$.fn.dataTable.render.moment is not a function`. I'm using Laravel 8.54 with `laravel-mix`. Here is my `app.js` where i load the libraries :

```js
require('./bootstrap');

$('.toast').toast('show')

$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})


window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
window.toastr = require('toastr')

require('moment')
require('../../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js')
require('datetime-moment')
require('../../node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4')
require('../../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js')
require('../../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable.js')
require('datatables.net-responsive')
```

I'm asking here because i saw many subjects treating this issue but none of these use npm. Does anyone has to deal with this issue ? Thank in advance

Comment: why `$.fn.dataTable.render.moment` and not just `moment` ?, moment has nothing to do with jQuery..

Comment: @Keith it seems that is a function defined in the `datetime-moment` plugin which is a plugin for datatable using moment for formatting datetime. But i'm a bit noob with those libraries, i have just following this documentation of datatable : https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/datetime

Answer (score 0):

It's a plugin code from datatables.net

You can download it from here:
https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.5/dataRender/datetime.js